# In three.js r57, objects that are not double-sided do not show up

Tags: three.js, textures

I am upgrading my application from three.js -r51 to -r57 (I got started before -r58 was released).  When I did, I noticed that any of my 3D collada models that did not have in them a line like this:

```
<extra><technique><double_sided>1</double_sided></technique></extra>
```

did not render.

It appears that the polygons are being culled. If I force `_gl.disable( _gl.CULL_FACE );` my model shows up as expected. But why would it cull all of my faces all of the time? (even if I had the winding order backward, I should see the other side of the object, right?)

Comment: The model that comes with three.js models\collada\monster\monster.dae has <double_sided>0</double_sided> and renders fine so you must be doing something else in your application.

Comment: Hmm ... quite right.  And it appears that my single-sided models still show up in the ColladaLoader example.  So, I must be doing something that wasn't an issue in r51, but is in r57.  Does that spark any ideas @gaitat (or anyone for that matter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my parameter to `setFaceCulling` wasn't right.  I was passing `false` instead of a culling mode.

With the r51 implementation, `false` happened to disable all culling.

With the r57 implementation, it dumped me into the new default behavior ... which is to enable culling and set it to cull both front and back faces.

So, I was able to fix it ... but I'm not sure I would have made that the default behavior.  ;o)